# void Start() not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity 4.3 with 2D mode. But for some reason the `void Start()` function isn't being called on the start of the scene. I even attached a `Debug.Log("Hello");` to the start function but it doesn't even do that so I know that the `Start()` function isn't being called. Although, the `Update()` function is called.

Here is the script.

```
private void Start()
{
    this.animation.Stop();
    Debug.Log("Hello");
}
```

You can see, there is an Update method which does work.

**EDIT:** Whole script:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 300);
public Vector2 moveForce = new Vector2(0, 300);
public Vector2 sideForce = new Vector2 (250, 0);
public GameObject obstacle;
public float scrollSpeed = 30;
public AnimationClip fly;
public GameObject player;

private float speed = 10.0f;

private void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("hi!");
    this.animation.Stop();
    Debug.Log("Hello");
}

private void Update() {
    onTouch();

    int fingerCount = 0;
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
        if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
            fingerCount++;

    }
    /*if (fingerCount > 0)
    {
        player.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        player.rigidbody2D.AddForce (moveForce);
    }*/
    try
    {
        player.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        player.rigidbody2D.AddForce (moveForce);

    } 
    catch(UnityException e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Fail");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("right"))
    {
        player.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.right;
        player.rigidbody2D.AddForce (sideForce);
    }

    accelorometer();
}

// Die by collision
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    Die();
}

private void Die()
{
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}

private void accelorometer()
{   
    // Get the accelerometer data:      
    Vector2 acceleration = Input.acceleration;

    // Get the forward value from one of the three channels in the acceleration data:
    float translation = acceleration.x * speed;

    // Make it move 10 meters per second instead of 10 meters per frame
    translation *= Time.deltaTime;  

    // Move translation along the object's z-axis
    player.transform.Translate (translation, 0, 0);
}

private void onTouch()
{
    /*int fingerCount = 0;

    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
        if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled)
            fingerCount++;

    }

    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (moveForce);
    }

    if (fingerCount > 0) 
    {
        player.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        player.rigidbody2D.AddForce (moveForce);
    }*/

    if(Input.GetKeyDown ("up"))
    {
        Debug.Log("ghjkl");

        player.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        player.rigidbody2D.AddForce (moveForce);
    }

    //print("User has " + fingerCount + " finger(s) touching the screen");
}
```

Comment: Is your script's component enabled/ticked on the game object in the editor?

Comment: Yes its ticked, Thanks @Chris

Comment: Have you tried to put the `Debug.Log` on the top of the Start function, just in case there is not animation and something bad happen on Stop animation line?

Comment: Tried that, still not working @kreys

Comment: And you're certainly sure that the script, it's `GameObject` and all it's parents are enabled?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the script is attached to the player.

Comment: can you maybe post all of the script or at least the class context? are you deriving from monobehaviour? Also is Update() getting called? What about Awake()?

Comment: Could you please show us the entire MonoBehaviour?

Comment: No error msgs? What if you comment `this.animation.Stop ();` ? is `Awake` working? Close Unity and open it again? :P

Comment: In unity it's possible to clear console, so it's possible your debug messages get cleared before you can see them. Add something else ... heck you can try adding infinite loop and see if unity hangs.

Comment: How do you know the 'Update()' gets called? You don't have debug statement there. If you know because coded behavior is working, it might be running a different script. Add Log.Debug to Update, make sure this is the actual script that's configured to run.

Comment: @Alex, Update does get called because the code is running in there. And I have no errors in the console

Comment: Did u make sure you are showing debug messages? Also add a debug line in your update to make sure.

Comment: I don't see any reason in particular why it shouldn't work. Would it be at all possible for you to create and share a minimal project which exhibits the behaviour you're talking about?

Comment: The only possibility I see is something i dont know if its possible to happen: if you copied&paste that "Start" word from another place with a type of text codification and for some reason unity does not support it then "Start" is not write properly. Delete the function and retype each character again. (just a crazy thing i agree)

Comment: [Monobehaviour Life Cycle](http://www.richardfine.co.uk/2012/10/unity3d-monobehaviour-lifecycle/) It does not solve your `Start()` method call problem. But you can use `Awake()` or `OnEnable()` for script start-up.

Answer (score 1):

You just copy the contents of that script and delete it. then  create a new script with same code and attach it to the gameObject. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this also. I've managed to solve it by changing **Logging*** to **Full** in the bottom of **Player Settings/Other Settings**